# (C) Allow infinite of numbers to be entered, reverse the order of entered numbers & end program when 0 is entered

Tags: c, integer, reverse, infinite

I'm working on a project at the moment where I have to allow a user to enter an infinite amount of numbers and reverse the order of those entered numbers and end the program if 0 is entered. I did something similar, except the one I did set the amount of numbers the user could enter, so for example in the code below, I allowed the user to enter only three numbers, reverse the order and end when -1 is entered.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAX 3 // Defining max amount of numbers to be entered to 3
main()
{
    int numbers[MAX], i, end;
    printf ("Please enter %d integers:\n", MAX);
        for (i = 0; i < MAX; i++){
         scanf("%d", &numbers[i]);
         if (numbers[i]==-1){ // Loop ends when -1 is entered
          for (end=i; end<MAX; end++)
           numbers[end]='\0'; // Nulls the value of blank locations in the array
        i=MAX;  
         }
        }
    printf ("\nThe values in reverse order are:\n");
    for (i = MAX-1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if(numbers[i]!='\0') // Will not print null values in the array
        printf("\n%d ", numbers[i]);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

How can I go about achieving this? I'm guessing I won't be able to use an array, and I'm pretty new to this so...

Comment: Since you tagged this as C++, may we suggest a solution that uses a standard C++ container instead of a raw C-style array?

Comment: Use `std::vector` instead of an array and use a `do` loop instead of a for loop.

Comment: array won't let you to input infinite numbers. though you try to set the array size to be dynamic, its kind of a pain, you could use stack instead array. so you can easily pop the reverse order

Comment: Well is there any way to do this using 'raw C-style'?

Comment: `numbers[end]='\0';` numbers[] is an int array. You dont need the `'\o'`, just `0` will suffice. [not fatal] But: `if (numbers[i]==-1){ ` you wanted to stop when a zero was entered. make up your mind! BTW: infinite != MAX

Answer (score 1):

No, arrays can't be grown dynamically (not without some extra tinkering, see comment below) so they can't hold an *infinite* amount of items.

You'll need some structure you can grow, C doesn't provide one so you'll have to use a third party implementation or write your own. A stack fits your problem the best.

Also, your loop will have to go on until -1 is entered. Either an infinite loop with a break statement, or a do-while loop that checks the entered number.

---

EDIT: The original question targeted C++, my original answer, below, is no longer relevant.

You want to look into C++'s STL. [`std::vector`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/), [`std::deque`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/deque/deque/) or [`std::stack`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stack/stack/) for example, would be useful in your case.

Comment: Well, this answer has been accepted, so I won't bother posting one, but the correct answer is that arrays *can* be grown dynamically using `realloc`. Of course, the array size is still limited to available memory, not infinite.

Comment: @user3386109 true, although `realloc` may *move* it, I didn't consider reallocation to be the same as growth. And yes, of course it can't be really infinite, that's why I put infinite in italics :P. I'll edit my answer a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a std::vector to do this.

Here's the declaration of your std::vector. Where the  tells the vector you want it to be a vector of type int

```
std::vector<int> numbers;
```

Then to add to the end of the std::vector you use push_back(), which puts the integer onto the back of the array. The size of the vector will dynamically increase as you push more elements on to the back.

```
int input;
numbers.push_back(input);
```

Then to iterator through it you can use a reverse iterator or just iterate the same way you have been doing it using numbers.size() to find out how many elements are in the vector.